# Best way to apply rate limit/throttling on multi processes API caller - using Celery

Tags: python, api, celery, throttling, rate-limiting

Here is the scenario:
I have 10 Celery workers which send HTTP requests(via Requests) to an external API server. That API server has an API rate limit 1000 request/second.
What I want to do is having a API request throttling on my side to avoid hit the rate limit.
My first thought is to have a Redis for Celery workers and keep the count of API requests on Redis. Is there another/best practice to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the @celery.task(rate_limit='1000/s') annotation, you can read more about it here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html

Answer (score 1):

Celery supports [exponential backoff](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.retry_backoff) and [automatic retries](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.autoretry_for) for exceptions.

If you prefer to never get a `429 Too Many Requests` at all, your approach of tracking the number of API requests you make is correct. It is called a [token bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) and you might find a generic implementation for your use-case, e.g. [django-simplekeys](https://github.com/jamesturk/django-simplekeys) sounds like it already does what you have in mind.

If you do a fixed number of API requests per task, it's easiest to annotate your task with the Celery [`rate_limit`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#Task.rate_limit). It also uses a token bucket internally.